# Searching for a specific bibliography style

Tags: bibliographies

I'm trying to obtain a bibliography which looks like this:
[image]

The most important aspects that I need are:

- In the citation there must be [FirstAuthorSurname, year], it's very important because I found another style which puts the last author surname in the brackets;
- The authors' name in the bibliography must be in this order: N. Surname, not Surname N.;
- I need the possibility to sort bibliography items alphabetically by the name in the brackets.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using `biblatex`. It takes the `trad-alpha` as the base style and the output is obtained by some (simple) customisation of the label.

```
\DeclareLabelalphaNameTemplate{
  \namepart{family}
}
```

The template above is just to tell we are going to use the family name part to create the label.

```
\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate{
 \labelelement{\field[names=1,noalphaothers]{labelname}}
 \labelelement{\literal{,~}}
 \labelelement{\field{year}}
}
```

For the label, the first optional parameter (names=1`) is to instruct to consider only the family name of the first author. The second`noapohaohters` is to prevent to put a market when there are multiple authors.

The final step is to adjust the definition of the bibliography (a list), where we set the indent of the list to a fixed width instead of the width of the (longest) label.

```
\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
    {\list
       {\printtext[labelalphawidth]{%
          \printfield{labelalpha}%
          \printfield{extraalpha}}}
       {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\parindent}%
        \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
        \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
        \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
        \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
        \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}%
        \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{##1\hss}}
    {\endlist}
    {\item}%
```

A complete file looks like:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[giveninits=true,style=trad-alpha]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareLabelalphaNameTemplate{
  \namepart{family}
}

\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate{
 \labelelement{\field[names=1,noalphaothers]{labelname}}
 \labelelement{\literal{,~}}
 \labelelement{\field{year}}
}

\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
    {\list
       {\printtext[labelalphawidth]{%
          \printfield{labelalpha}%
          \printfield{extraalpha}}}
       {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\parindent}%
        \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
        \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
        \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
        \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
        \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}%
        \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{##1\hss}}
    {\endlist}
    {\item}%

\begin{document}

\cite{knuth:ct:a,knuth:ct:b,knuth:ct:c}
\cite{murray}

\printbibliography  
\end{document}
```

and produces

[image]